# How to update MySQL Server, MySQL Client and phpMyAdmin to the latest stable versions on my local machine running on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, server, mysql, phpmyadmin, client

I'm using **64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** on my machine. I've already installed **LAMP server** on my machine.

I'm using following **Apache HTTP Server** version.

I got following information after I type following command into my machine's terminal :

```
apachectl -V

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 22:57:50
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:36
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

I'm using following **PHP** version on my machine. Following is the command that I run and the information I seen:

```
php -v

PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:32:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

When I hit the URL : `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` from the address bar of my browser, Log in screen of phpMyAdmin loaded then I entered the Username and Password to login. After logging in I saw following details on right pane.

```
**MySQL**    

 - Server: Localhost via UNIX socket    
 - Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
 - Protocol version: 10
 - User: root@localhost
 - MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)


**Web server**
 - Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
 - MySQL client version: 5.5.40
 - PHP extension: mysqli

**phpMyAdmin**

 - Version information: 3.4.10.1deb1
 - Documentation
 - Wiki
 - Official Homepage
 - Contribute
 - Get support
 - List of changes
```

I don't know whether the versions of softwares **MySQL Server, MySQL Client and phpMyAdmin** are the latest stable versions or not. Please guide me in this regard.

Now I want to update **MySQL Server, MySQL Client and phpMyAdmin**  to the latest stable versions on my local machine that is running on **64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**.

What should be the efficient, reliable, secure and easiest way to do this?

Please provide me help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most efficient would be to just upgrade your system to 14.04 to get closer to stable.  Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: That would be best. Support for 12.04 is ending and you should upgrade to 14.04 ASAP. You will only get security updates on 12.04 from this point forward.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect from an [Ubuntu LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) release such as yours to have the latest stable version of all those software you mentioned.
You are 2-years into the 5-years support period of your release,
so I think this is a reasonable expectation.

Upgrading to 14.04 doesn't seem like a great idea.
Upgrading is a sensitive operation not to be taken lightly,
potentially a major hurdle.
The support period of 14.04 will end one year earlier than the current,
so you would have to upgrade one year earlier.

To update the software you listed, you can use this command:

```
apt-get install names_of_packages
```

This will upgrade only the selected packages.
If you don't mind,
it's good to keep your entire system up to date, with:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

If, on the other hand, the version of Apache/MySQL bundled with 12.04 is really too old for you,
then you might want to consider installing the latest version from source.
However at this point the benefits of this approach over upgrading to 14.04 become questionable.

In any case,
before you do any major changes (`apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` don't count as major changes, they should be safe),
I recommend to create a clone system (in VirtualBox or other),
export your current settings and reimport in the clone and test carefully.

Comment: When you say @PHPLover is 2 of 5 years into support, I hope you realize that only those first two years give support for stable software. The other three years are just used for security updates to give server owners time to upgrade to 14.04. Therefore, a new version of his software will not get into the Ubuntu 12.04 repos unless it has a security fix.

Comment: The official instructions are at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10. Make sure you follow the directions for a server system. Before you do it, make sure you remove the tex-common and flightgear packages if you have them installed before the upgrade.

Comment: 14.04 will not be unsupported in 2 years. Well, you won't get stable software updates, but you'll get another three years to upgrade to 16.04. I don't recommend upgrading to 15.04 as it's not an LTS release and you'll have to upgrade in 6 months after installing. However, you do make a good point if you meant 16.04. If you want the latest stable MySQL and phpAdmin like you asked in your question, go ahead and upgrade to 14.04, and I'm assuming you do otherwise you never would have asked this question. However, if you choose to just keep using 12.04 and upgrade to 16.04 in 18 months...

Comment: then you would have to upgrade to 14.04 then to 16.04 at once because you can't upgrade to 12.04 straight to 16.04. I guess it's just a matter of preference if you want 14.04 now or later. Every LTS release is supported for the exact same amount of time, so 14.04 does not get only two years of support. That is for latest stable software. When 16.04 comes out, 14.04 gets three years of security updates to give people time to upgrade to 16.04. I think it's best you back up and upgrade to 14.04 to get the latest software and get it out of the way. You can't upgrade directly from 12.04 to 16.04.